# How to interpret "брать упорством"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Когда таланта нет, приходится **брать упорством**.

```
=??? ..., you have to be persistent.
```

I wonder if "брать + instrumental noun" makes for some idiomatic expression?

Comment: I recommend you to use google or yandex - and there's no slightest tint of irony in my words - when you search in quotes - "брать упорством" - you search for exact matches, and it can give you pretty overview.

Comment: "брать + instrumental noun" means "To get (to achieve) [something] by using <noun>"

Answer (score 6):

Other similar examples would be: "брать измором" -- "to wear down (the issue, person, etc.)"; "брать нервом" (oldish; used in 1930s "Вратарь республики") -- "to do/achieve by the strength of spirit, not by physical strength"; "брать нахрапом" -- "to get/achieve (something) by being extremely pushy".

Answer (score 4):

It does. The phrase means **`to conquer with perseverance`**

**Брать** here is *`to conquer, to capture, to seize`* in a military sense or simply *`to take`* which in English to the best of my knowledge can also have that meaning.

There's a proverb:

> Смелость города берёт

Which means that towns or castles can be captured with enough courage and bravery.

Comment: In this very phrase it means "to achieve (being persistent)".